# How To Set Screen Resolution To 1280x960 In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, graphics, resolution, screen

Here is the output of `xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
   1280x960_60.00   59.9  
   960p           60.0  
  1280x1024_60_new (0xc9)  138.5MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1504 total 1728 skew    0 clock   80.2KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1069           clock   75.0Hz
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is like so...

```
 xrandr --output VGA-1 --size 1280x960
```

**Update**
If that doesn't help here is a [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67700) that might.

Comment: Thank you So Much I Get It Here [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67700/change-screen-resolution-on-linux-mint)  and It Workout

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in compiz I think.

Under General Options/Display Settings/Outputs

You can change the current settings there in Edit.